# How to install erlang in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, erlang

Just as the title says, how do I install erlang in my Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Refer this [link](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-quiz/wiki/InstallingErlangLinux). This will help you to install erlang though you already download the Source Package or not.

Answer (score 37):

Here is how. Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install erlang erlang-doc
```

Answer (score 15):

You can find more up-to-date packages [here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) (Ubuntu 12.04 has R14B04, while the latest version is R15B02).  Download the appropriate package and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i esl-erlang_15.b.2-1~ubuntu~precise_amd64.deb
```

(adjust as appropriate for the 32-bit package)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to make this file executable (`chmod u+x`) and run it with `sudo`.

```
apt-get update
# replace libwxgtk2.8-dev with libwxgtk3.0-dev for Ubuntu 16.04
apt-get --fix-missing -y install build-essential m4 libncurses5-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev libgmp3-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libglu1-mesa-dev fop xsltproc default-jdk
mkdir -p /src/erlang
cd /src/erlang
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B01.tar.gz 
tar -xvzf otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz 
chmod -R 777 otp_src_R16B01 
cd otp_src_R16B01 
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: `chmod 777` is never a good idea, and in this case it's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you install it through the Ubuntu Software Center.

**To install erlang from Ubuntu Software Center:**

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Type  `erlang`  into the search. Under the 'Concurrent, real-time, distributed functional language' title...
3. Check the Add-on, though optional, for additional features.
4. Click on 'install' to install it.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code, you could do this:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential m4 libncurses5-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev libgmp3-dev libwxgtk2.8-dev libglu1-mesa-dev fop xsltproc default-jdk
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz
tar -xvzf otp_src_R16B01.tar.gz
chmod -R 777 otp_src_R16B01
cd otp_src_R16B01
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

**Note:** in some commands it will be necessary have *root* permissions, so it's adviced to use `sudo` or `su` when it's asked. (as you can see some commands already have `sudo` as prefix)

Comment: It is unnecesary to set the executable bit to all the files! Also, `make install` will fail if you are not root.

Comment: Also next time just link to the complete script not copy just part of it

Comment: Thank you Paulo Oliveira. I didn't understand why they down voting your answer. If some one is installing from the source, the first line (apt-get) is very important. A tip: there is no need the `chmod' line.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to search the software repository to see if the package you are looking for is in and the repository, and that the version of the software is in the repository.

You can open the terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+t`, after doing so simply run the commands below:

```
:~$ apt-cache search erlang

// if erlang exists in the current repository, you can check its dependencies with:
:~$ apt-cache depends erlang

// if erlang is in the repository and its the version you want to install
// gain super-user privileges
:~$ sudo bash

// and install with apt-get
:~# apt-get -y install erlang
:~# apt-get -y install erlang-doc
:~# exit
:~$
```

I hope this helps!