# Installed Erlang in ubuntu but found nowhere to open the application

Tags: erlang

As the title says, I used `sudo apt-get install erlang erlang-doc` commmand in my terminal and it dicated me that it was installed successfully.

However I found nowhere to open the installed erlang program. I tried to search it on the top left button (where I can search the application through my computer or on the internet).. There is nothing found..

One guess from me is that I only installed the erlang working environemnt instead of the Erlang shell that I can actually test things on it like I used to do on windows. So maybe that is the reason I couldn't find it? I am not quite sure about that yet because I just newly turned into Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: btw I also tried to use `locate erlang` ,it promts to me with many lines of messages but still didn't forward me to the destination folder or something.

Comment: You should try simply enter`erlang`.

Comment: @Chromium I did try just enter `erlang` in the terminal. didn't work also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to open `erlang` interpreter is:

```
erl
```

Also note that Ubuntu repositories often doesn't contain the latest versions of software. If you want to install the current version of `erlang`, you'll have to compile it from [source](http://www.erlang.org/download/) as described in [How to install erlang in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190612/how-to-install-erlang-in-ubuntu-12-04) or [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/#Installing-on-Debian-Ubuntu)